# JMeter - How to load result file?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have done a test JMeter and am able to get results.csv or result.jtl.

How do I load it into JMeter from the GUI and command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What do you mean by "load"? You have the results, now you need to analyze them. It can be done in different ways depending on how you plan to represent results and what metrics do you need to report, for example:

1. Using [Microsoft Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) or equivalent like [Libre Office Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/)
2. Using JMeter GUI:

   - Open JMeter GUI
   - Add [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice to the Test Plan (for example [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) is quite good)
   - Using "Browse" button locate your results file and load it
   - JMeter will parse the results file, perform necessary calculations and display the metrics. If you need you can click "Save Table Data" to export the results for later re-use

     [image: JMeter Listener display results]
3. You can plot some charts reflecting the test metrics using [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
4. You can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) like:

   ```
   jmeter -g your_result_file.jtl -o /where/you/want/the/dashboard/to/be/generated
   ```
5. You can use a 3rd-party analysis service like [JAnalyzer](http://epireum.com/page-section/janalyser/) or [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) to create [jtl](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JtlFiles) and result files.

Write in listener filename: results.csv